# PhalconPHP and phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, phalcon

I've been following the [docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/unit-testing) to set up phpunit with phalcon. I have the example working.

However, I now want to actually put it to use and test my own classes, to do this I understand I need to register the directories in the loader, but instead of repeating the directories that are already defined in the config, I'm wanting to include the config in the php unit test helper class (from a `phalcon project' command). This sounds simple but is anything but.

Do I have to add additional code to access the $config?

Am I right in assuming that the docs are missing a large amount of code regarding testing your own classes, or, should it work straight out the box after following the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to implement this myself the basic idea is below for an implementation example head to: https://github.com/SavvySoftWorksLLC/phalcon_3_2_devtools_sample_project/tree/pks/setup_phpunit

If you externalize your loader like

```
<?php

$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */
$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        $config->application->controllersDir,
        $config->application->modelsDir
    ]
)->register();
```

And then call it in your entrypoint like this:

```
include ROOT_PATH . "/../app/config/loader.php";
```

You will be able to reuse the same loader in your test helper provided you initialize a fresh DI container like the docs mention.

To give the big picture I pushed up a out of the box app create by devtools for you to look at.

Loader: https://github.com/SavvySoftWorksLLC/phalcon_3_2_devtools_sample_project/blob/master/app/config/loader.php

EntryPoint:
https://github.com/SavvySoftWorksLLC/phalcon_3_2_devtools_sample_project/tree/master/public

Comment: `include ROOT_PATH . "/../app/config/loader.php";` was one of the first things I tried, which leads to `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: config in /var/www/api/app/config/loader.php on line 10` when trying to access the config value. If I add `ROOT_PATH . '/../app/models'` to the $loader->registerDirs as defined in the TestHelper I end up with the error `Phalcon\Di\Exception: Service 'modelsManager' wasn't found in the dependency injection container`

Comment: One of the differences I had to make to the documentation sample was the ordering of the DI factory creation. At this point I was able to sort it out here https://github.com/SavvySoftWorksLLC/phalcon_3_2_devtools_sample_project/blob/pks/setup_phpunit/test/TestHelper.php

Comment: I took a second look at this and managed to get it up and running, but am now getting `modelsManager wasn't found in the dependency injection container`¬

Comment: And to answer my own comment, the incubator contains a ModelTestCase abstract class which handles the model manager, just be sure to include your model directory in the registerDirs